# Provide single @Bean that can be used to inject in multiple interfaces

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, autowired

Consider the following piece of code

```
public interface Iface1 { }
public interface Iface2 { }

public class A implements Iface1, Iface2 {

}

@Configuration
public class AutoConfig {

  @Bean
  Iface1 provideIface1Impl() {
      return new A();  // instance no 1234
  }

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnBean(A.class)
  @Autowired
  Iface2 provideIface2Impl(A aImpl) {
    return aImpl;
  }
}
```

I would like the second `@Bean` method to be autowired with the instance from the first one (1234) and I'd like the second `@Bean` method to return the same instance, so that I can use the same instance for clients of `Iface1` and `Iface2`.

Current problem is that spring doesn't run the second `@Bean` because there is no `@Bean` of type `A.class` - the created bean is considered as `Iface1` even though it is of type `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define bean A. When injecting IFace1 and Iface2 they will automatically resolve to A (if A is the only implementation of course).

```
@Bean
public A a() {
    return new A();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to define only one `@Bean`. It will create a singleton:

```
@Bean
public A a() {
      return new A();
}
```

Then just use the name of this bean in `@Qualifier` annotation:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("a")
private Iface1 iface1;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("a")
private Iface2 iface2;
```

Comment: `@Qualifier` is needed when there are multiple implementations of the same interface. No need in qualifier if there is only one implementation (doesn't matter if it implements multiple interfaces or a single one).

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to what others have answered, I'd like to cover that part of the question that touches bean's dependencies.
To inject a dependency to a `@Bean`-annotated method, there are two ways:

- [Call another @Bean-method directly](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-injecting-dependencies)
- [Add parameter to the method](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-dependencies)

Examples of both:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public Foo foo() {
        return new Foo();
    }

    @Bean
    public Bar bar() {
        return new Bar(foo());
    }

    @Bean
    public Baz baz(Foo foo) {
        return new Baz(foo);
    }
}
```

So your provideIface2Impl could look like this:

```
@Bean
Iface2 provideIface2Impl(A aImpl) {
    return aImpl;
}

// or...

@Bean
Iface2 provideIface2Impl() {
    return (Iface2)provideIface1Impl();
}
```

**But don't use it this way**, it will lead to subtle bugs like double-proxying or "No unique bean of type" error, etc. Prefer what [Gorazd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47529153/8868289) suggested.